# Copy Data from Production/Sandbox to Sandbox after sandbox refresh in salesforce

Tags: sandbox, data, production, data-synchronization

We need to load data from sandbox to sandbox for testing & Dev proposes.
Right we are using Microsoft ETL for this purpose, but that is too lengthy and we need to maintain metadata after every releases goes to production.

So i want any salesforce tool through which we can achieve this with investing too much time, later autmate also. i have tried few salesforce  app in appexchange, but that does't work.Any one using any app and suggest that.

We have to load customised set of data not whole due to storage restriction.

Comment: your question is too broad

Comment: You should search the Salesforce AppExchange.

Comment: I don't think this question is on topic according to the guidelines in the [help], but you may wish to look at https://www.smartsandbox.com.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Never came across this smartsandbox site, but seems really cool and promising.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this question is on topic, but you may wish to look at a little known tool developed by some of my former colleagues: https://www.smartsandbox.com.